# Error in partial preprocessing in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

This is my make file. And, I'm trying to run partial preprocessing using unifdef. But it fails after executing unifdef.

```
#HELLO = world
HELLO_WORLD = $(HELLO) world!
COMMA := ,
VAR_ARG_LIST_A := $(subst $(COMMA), ,$(VAR_ARG_LIST))
VAR_ARG_LIST_1 := $(word 1,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
VAR_ARG_LIST_2 := $(word 2,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
VAR_ARG_LIST_3 := $(word 3,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
VAR_ARG_LIST_4 := $(word 4,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
VAR_ARG_LIST_5 := $(word 5,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
VAR_ARG_LIST_6 := $(word 6,$(VAR_ARG_LIST_A))
all:
#       echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_1)
#       echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_2)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_3)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_4)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_5)
        echo $(VAR_ARG_LIST_6)
        unifdef -USW1 -USW2 -USW3 -USW4 -USW5 -USW6 -t file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Error is

```
make VAR_ARG_LIST=AW1,AW2
echo AW1
AW1
echo AW2
AW2
echo 

echo 

echo 

echo 

unifdef -USW1 -USW2 -USW3 -USW4 -USW5 -USW6 -t file1.txt > file2.txt
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Contents of file1.txt is:

```
#ifdef SW1
This is a file1
#endif
This is file file 1
This is file file 2
This is file file3
```

Contents of file2.txt is:

```
This is file file 1
This is file file 2
This is file file3
```

make fails right after executing unifdef command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the exit code of unifdef, then simply ensure that the recipe line exits with a true value.  For example:

```
unifdef -USW1 -USW2 -USW3 -USW4 -USW5 -USW6 -t file1.txt > file2.txt || true
```

will ensure that the line always succeeds.

Comment: +1 Nice. I fiddled with `&& 0`, but couldn't remember `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unifdef exits with status 1 if the output differs from the input (that is, if it does anything), but Make interprets a non-zero status as failure and aborts. You can get around this with a hyphen:

```
-unifdef -USW1 -USW2 -USW3 -USW4 -USW5 -USW6 -t file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Now Make will report

```
make: [all] Error 1 (ignored)
```

and keep going. (There may be a way to suppress the error message, if it annoys you.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I will try to find a way to suppress the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.7 of unifdef (which was released in March 2013) has a -x option to control the exit status logic, so it plays more nicely with make. You might want to use -x1 so that make will ensure that unifdef did actually make changes. See http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/